# sscanf ignoring `00` while I need to add it to a char array

Tags: c

I am reading a binary file using `fread`. Inside that binary file, there are hex codes that I need to store in a char array, and I am using sscanf to parse them, as such:
Buffer has the whole data, and I know how many of them are there, which is stored in an int `size`.
Example of this can be: `B8 04 00 8B 5C`.

The problem: whenever sscanf sees a `00`, and because we're storing them as characters, it thinks that it has ended, and all characters after `00` become unidentified characters, for example, 32 once became `5D` and such.

A small snippet:

```
int size=5;
char codes[255];
sscanf(buffer, "%sizec", codes);
.
.
.
printf("%2X ", (unsigned char) codes[i]);
```

The output: `B8 04 00 99 58`

while it should be: `B8 04 00 3B 5C`

Comment: Apparently your `buffer` is not a string. You must use a string in `sscanf()`. With binary data you need to find another solution.

Comment: `"%sizec"` is a `%s` (i.e. NUL terminated string) followed by `"izec"` (i.e. a literal match).  It does not mean 5 characters.

Comment: `char *buffer = (char*)malloc(BUFFER_MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));`
it is.

Comment: Why don't you just `memcpy` 5 bytes?

Comment: @pat, more explanation please?

Comment: Apparently, you just want to copy `size` bytes from the front of `buffer` to the front of `codes`.  That is just `memcpy(codes, buffer, size);`.

Comment: Interesting. Any other way than memcpy?

Comment: What did memcpy ever do to you?  Yes, you can make it as complicated as you want...  But you would be hard pressed to make it simpler!  If all you want to do is print the bytes, you could just leave them in `buffer`, but that's crazy right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to copy size bytes from the front of `buffer` to the front of `codes`, then:

```
memcpy(codes, buffer, size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the inconsistency of your format string, you cannot use `sscanf` on binary data at all.

The problem that is most relevant to your case is that the `scanf` family of functions treat `'\0'` as a null termination of the input string. The values `0x99 0x58` that you see there after `0x00` is simply a "leftover garbage" that is left there from the time the uninitialized memory block has been allocated.

However, the good news is that you do not need `sscanf`: all it does for you is copying the content of the string to the array of `codes` - something a plain [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) can do much more efficiently.

Comment: Even after I have saved them in an allocated buffer of chars?

Comment: @TheNotMe It does not matter what you did before or after: once `sscanf` sees a zero, it thinks that the string that is passed to it as the input has ended.